# how do i detect two different keypresses in a specified time period?

Tags: time, keyboard, key, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script that, when I type "th" within a certain time period, it'll send the "Þ" symbol, but if I don't send the following "h", it will send the "₹" symbol instead. Trying to make this into a HotString.

I don't have any code to show what I've tried, but I've been through quite a bit of digging to try and figure it out without any result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t::
    Input, key_press, L1 T2
    If (key_press = "h")
        Send, Þ
    else
        Send, ₹
Return
```

Where:

- **key_press** can be any variable name.
- **L1** indicates the maximum allowed length of the input (a single character in this case).
- **T2** indicates the number of seconds to wait before terminating the input (2 seconds in this case).

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Input.htm